# How to properly wait for an unawaitable operation to complete

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, bitmapimage

In my app, I created a class, SerializableBitmapImage, that displays a default image while another image downloads from the internet. It also allows serializing the downloaded image as a byte array so the image does not need to be downloaded on every app launch.
I currently have a SerializableBitmapImage in class "Card" which is saved right when the card data completes downloading:

```
var resp = await AppData.API.GetCards();
if (resp != null)
{
    if (AppData.CardsData == null)
        AppData.CardsData = new CardsData();
    AppData.CardsData.Update(resp);
    AppData.SaveCards();
    FillCards();
}
```

But, sometimes the images in SerializableBitmapImage are not finished downloading by the time AppData.SaveCards() is called, causing the images to not be saved.
So, I'm looking for a way to delay saving until the images are downloaded. Right now, I'm downloading the images in SerializableBitmapImage's constructor like so:

```
Image = new BitmapImage(defaultUri); //set to default while downloading
BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage { CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None };
img.ImageOpened += (sender, e) => //download successful, set Image to downloaded image
{
    Image = sender as BitmapImage;
    NotifyPropertyChanged("Image");
};
img.UriSource = downloadUri; //download the image
```

I created a Task in SerializableBitmapImage to wait for the image to be completed, but I'm not sure if it does its job in a healthy way.

```
public async Task WaitForImageDownload()
{
    while (Image == null || Image.UriSource.OriginalString == "Assets/MainPage/DefaultCard.png")
        await Task.Delay(100); //check again if completed in 100ms
}
```

Then, in AppData.SaveCards(), I wait for all the images to be downloaded before I save the cards:

```
Task[] tasks = new Task[CardsData.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < CardsData.Count; i++)
    tasks[i] = CardsData[i].CardImage.WaitForImageDownload();
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Is this the proper way to wait for an operation that is not awaitable to complete? Or, is there a way to force the images to download immediately?
Thanks for your help!
Elliott

Comment: A quick suggestion, methods which can be awaited should end with an `Async` suffix, i.e. `public async Task WaitForImageDownloadAsync()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're close. Of course, every time you are busy-waiting alarm bells should go off:

```
while (Image == null || Image.UriSource.OriginalString == "Assets/MainPage/DefaultCard.png")
    await Task.Delay(100); //check again if completed in 100ms
```

That's not perfect. This will work but you are spinning up the CPU unnecessarily and you introduce a delay that might be perceived by the user. Better only wake up one the condition you are waiting for is true. Let the Image notify you:

```
public async Task WaitForImageDownload()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    image.ImageOpened += (o, e) =>;
    {
        tcs.SetResult(true);
    };

    image.ImageFailed += (o, e) =>;
    {
        tcs.SetResult(false);
    };

    //set the source after the events have been attached
    //or, check whether the image has been loaded already and only
    //attach if it has
    image.SetSource(TODO); 

    await tcs.Task;

}
```

(Better move that waiting into a helper method.)

Your usage of `Task.WhenAll` is a good thing.

> Or, is there a way to force the images to download immediately?

Answering this literally: Of course not, that would violate physics. (I've no idea what you mean by that question...)

Comment: I didn't even know that class existed. But now I do :)
Thanks for your help!